# Hairy Ball Theorem on $\mathbb{S}^2$: a counter-example?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

Let $(U, (\theta, \varphi))$ be the spherical coordinate chart on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$, and consider the vector field on $U$ defined by $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}$. Then in this chart, the metric tensor $g_{ij}$ can be expressed as follows:

$$g_{ij} = d\varphi^2 + \sin^2\varphi \, d\theta^2. $$

This means that the vector $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \varphi} \Bigr|_{p} \in T_p\mathbb{S}^2$ has norm $1$ for any point $p \in U$. But this seems to contradict the Hairy Ball theorem, which says that every smooth vector field on $\mathbb{S}^2$ has to vanish somewhere. What's going on? What is wrong with this logic?

I think the problem is that the spherical coordinate chart on $\mathbb{S}^2$ is not a *global* chart. So perhaps this vector field defined on $U$ cannot be extended to a smooth vector field on the whole manifold. *My question is:* is there an intuitive geometric reason why we would expect that this vector field cannot be smoothly extended? Something involving pictures of vector fields would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This chart is not defined everywhere, hence the tangent vector isn't either. The hairy ball theorem shows precisely that this cannot be extended to all of $S^2$.

Comment: That chart doesn't cover the whole sphere.

Comment: If you draw a picture of this vector field you will see what goes wrong.

Comment: Moreover, there cannot be any chart covering $S^2$ and thus, you cannot expect to construct vector fields on $S^2$ like this. To see that, suppose that a chart covers all of $S^2$. Then $S^2$ should be diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. As $S^2$ is compact, this open subset would be compact. But there is no open compact subset in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Pedro I think that's what I'm struggling to see. I'm imagining the vector field $\partial / \partial \varphi$ as "combing" the hair on the sphere along its latitude lines. The vectors of this vector field appear to get shorter and shorter as we get closer to the north pole. But the metric tensor says that this vector field has norm $1$ everywhere on $U$, which doesn't line up with the picture. Is this way of visualizing the vector field $\partial / \partial \varphi$ correct?

Comment: @chaad When going near the poles, this vector field turn around the poles on concentric circle with thinner and thinner radius. By shrinking this circles on the poles, which direction would you expect the vector to point at?

Comment: @chaad In fact I did a confusion with $\partial_{\varphi}$ and $\partial_\theta$. In the $\partial_\varphi$ case, the vector field is orthogonal to all the concentric circles, and the question is the same: which direction would you expect this vector field to point at on the poles?

Comment: @Didier Okay, so $\partial_{\varphi}$ points away from the north pole and towards the south pole. And it has norm $1$ at each point. So I'm guessing that the problem is there is no way to define $\partial_{\varphi}$ at the poles so that it is continuous? Because at the south pole, for example, the arrows all point towards the south pole with norm $1$.

Comment: @chaad Exactly. There is no direction in which should be pointing at at the poles, because it should point at all directions in the same time if it was defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the hope a picture is worth a thousand words:
[image: A smooth vector field on the sphere minus the poles with no continuous extension]

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, where did you find this picture?

Comment: Glad to hear it's helpful; I made it using [ePiX](https://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/ePiX.html).